# start emacsclient with specific window geometry

Tags: emacsclient, frame-parameters

I am trying to convert my existing emacs setup to a client/daemon configuration.

A lot works as intended, but I do not manage to set the frame geometry to a fixed size. I do have the following in my `.emacs` file, which I find convenient:

```
(set-frame-size (selected-frame) 220 121)
(set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 0)
```

I understand that I need to specify this on the command line, with the `--frame-parameters` option, but I could not figure out what exactly to pass as argument.

```
emacsclient -c test.txt -F '???'
```

**UPDATE:** I modified my .emacs file to include the following:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 220))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 121))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(left . 0))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(top . 0))
```

This seems to do the job...